# Tool to convert string to BackgroundImage for Windows Phone 8 Live Tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Currently I'm trying to create a Live Tile where it pulls data from a JSON link, run some code to filter it and spits out the data on the FRONT side of the tile.

From Windows Phone 8's Flip Tile specification, only the back side of the tile can have text. I'd like to enable it for the front side so the user doesn't have to wait for the tile to flip. From what I understand, this can be achieved by converting my text to an image, and then set it as a BackgroundImage for my tile.

Windows Phone 7 had a tool called Ree7 which enables that, but I'd like to enable it for Windows Phone 8, medium and large tiles.

Additionally, it would be great if my tiles don't flip and remain on its front side.

Having extra images such as app icon on the tile would be an additional plus.

Can someone please point me to the right direction to proceed here? Using a pre-built tool (like a Ree7 for WP8) seems like the best way here.

Comment: I would recommend against doing that. Your text is going to be blurry due to the resolution upscale on highend devices. Better you pick a different tile template, such as the IconicTemplate.

Comment: I believe there should be a more elegant solution to the problem, for example, Calendar apps that support double-wide and medium tile, with tile flipping being optional: such as Appointile.

I believe IconicTile only allows Count for Medium tile?

Answer (score 0):

see if this tool could be useful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shintak/archive/2013/01/01/10418997.aspx

he hasn't provided the source, but you could possibly contact the blogger to get it.

Comment: Hmm, this tool doesn't allow dynamically updating the tile with the text gotten from JSON periodically.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/livetilehelper.aspx

I believe I found the answer to my question. However, if there are better, free alternatives that do not distort the text too much (such as Lawrence Gripper's old BBC News Mobile app, where text is extremely legible with little distortion), please do share it here.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few tutorials out there on [how to create custom tiles](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-create-cool-custom-tiles-in-a-windows-phone-application/). To avoid distortion, make sure the resolution of the `UserControl` and resulting image are correct for each tile size

Comment: Thank you for the link, Neil.

Another great link that I found in the mean time for future reference:
https://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Custom_Live_Tile_Layout_with_UserControl_as_image_source